# How do I get the Nuget Packages Window in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image]

I have installed VS 2022 and the first time I go to use the Nuget window (Nuget packages manager) it's not there!  Has it moved? Or should I reinstall VS 2022 ?

It's VS version 17.6.4

I did try a Windows layout reset, just in case, but I knew that wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't believe that option is available without an open project/solution. Can you confirm whether you have a solution/project opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a 'feature' of VS2022, at least on my PC. I start up VS, open the repos folder from Open Re3cent. I go to the Git tab and do a pull (just in case) and create a new branch. I switch to the Solution Explorer tab, there's my solution, all my code. I do a Build, but if fails on missing Nuget packages.
I go to Tools / Nuget Package Manage and Manage Nuget Packages for Solution is not there. It's Almost as if VS doesn't know the solution is open.
If I close VS and navigate to the sln file, I can open this and the Nuget menu is fine.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. As I said in my comment _"I don't believe that option is available without an open project/solution"_ and you had opened the folder and not the solution. When working like this VS "just sees" a bunch of files. This is how I would expect VS to work. It's not VS Code, and yes it is a feature.

Comment: Then what's the difference, visually, between opening a solution and a 'bunch of files'? I was quite happy to start coding until I noticed the Nugget thing.

Comment: If you open a folder then you're just dealing with a bunch of files and folders just as if you had opened it in VS Code or Windows Explorer. If you open the solution file (*.sln) then VS will treat it as a solution with all the intellisense and extra features you want out of an IDE like the ability to manage nuget packages through the UI.

Answer (score 2):

The option is "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...". As such I would not expect to see that option unless you have a solution open.

[image: Screenshot of VS 2022 NuGet Package Manager menu showing Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... option]

Failing that. Can you confirm that the option is configured for the menu (Tools -> Customize...). Do you have the cmdidAddPackagesForSolution command listed?

[image: Screenshot of VS 2022 Customize dialog showing menu options configured for "Tools | NuGet Package Manager" menu bar]

If not you should be able to add it using the Add Command... button

[image: Screenshot of Add Command dialog showing Tools category and the cmdidAddPackagesForSolution command highlighted]

Comment: Yes, I don't have that

Comment: @Azven I've added extra detail on customizing VS 2022s menu options for stuff you can check